# how to fetch a particular content from a website in ios

Tags: ios7, xcode5

please help me i am suffering from this problem long time .
how can i get content from URL if i know div id and class name of that URL so based on that i want to fetch the content.
i am using HTML parser but  problem is it only access .HTML sites which contain simple HTML code and i can not access which contain HTML tags like class and id.please help me. thanks in advance.
this is my HTMLParser.m code

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    currentHTMLElement.tag = elementname;
    currentHTMLElement.value = currentNodeContent;
    [elementArray addObject:currentHTMLElement];
    currentHTMLElement = nil;
    currentNodeContent = nil;
}
```

Comment: You can use native NSJSONSerialization  for parsing values.

Comment: can anyone give the example ?????

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to consult this tutorial and Apple Documentation. it will hopefully helps you:

**1)** http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

**2)** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.ht